# NIC Order in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a script where it will provide the NIC binding order like below. But is there anyway so that I can write a condition if binding order is `vEthernet*,storage` then

```
Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Aquamarine' height='25' align=center><B>$ServicesResult1</B></td>"
```

else

```
Add-Content $report "<td bgcolor= 'Yellow' height='25' align=center><B>$ServicesResult1</B></td>"
```

```cs
$result1 = Invoke-Command -ComputerName slcae212 -ScriptBlock {
    Function Get-BindOrder {
        $Binding = (Get-ItemProperty "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage").Bind
        $Return = New-Object PSobject
        $BindingOrder = @()
        foreach ($Bind in $Binding) {
            $DeviceId = $Bind.Split("\")[2]
            $Adapter = (Get-WmiObject Win32_Networkadapter | Where {$_.GUID -eq $DeviceId }).NetConnectionId
            $BindingOrder += $Adapter
        }
        $BindingOrder
    } #EndFunction
    CLS
    Get-BindOrder
}
$adapteresult1= $result1 -join ","
```

Output:

```
vEthernet (10.211.21.0_20),,storage,Ethernet 5,Ethernet 4,Ethernet 2,Ethernet 6,,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure where in your you need it but you can use a `regex` to check that:

```
vEthernet[^,]+?,storage
```

[image]

Now you can use that in an `if` statement using the `-match` operator:

```
if ($yourBinding -match 'vEthernet[^,]+?,,storage')
{
   # do something
}
else
{
   # do something else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With all respect, I don't think that you are on the correct way with programming this. I presume that you eventually want to reorder the `"HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage").Bind` and put that back in the registry. (Years ago I have had similar request and at created a `VBScript` for that.)

In your script, your currently trying to deal with the adapter names to redefine the order of the original bindingorder but the relation between the `$DeviceID` and the `$Adapter` name is completely lost in you current approach.
Instead of doing string manipulation it is better, faster and more native to PowerShell to work with objects in the form of an `array` or in this case even a `HashTable` or 'PSCustomObject' where you keep a related between the `$DeviceID` and the `$Adapter` name. I would like to point out here that you could possible have multiple `vEthernet` adpaters and that some `$adapter` names are apparently empty (there is nothing between two commas `...,,...`), but AFAIK that doesn't imply that you just can drop the `$DeviceID` (without adapter name) from the binding order...

I think there is a good example for your request written here:
https://seawin.org/2016/06/04/setting-binding-and-route-registry-entries/

Notes:

1. Your binding order could potential change on the fly e.g. if a user create a VPN connection or starts a VM, this probably means that you can not just run your fix at startup or logon but depending on the actual problem, you might have to fix it *as it happens* by setting a `NotificationQuery` event on the specific `HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Linkage` registry key.
2. Changing the binding order (on the fly) has a significant impact on the Operating System processes, besides that you CPU will raise, network connection are being reset and could be unavailable for a while. Therefor I advice you to check/flag whether the binding order really changed (where required) and only rewrite it when necessarily.
3. I doubt whether the known issues related to the binding order are the same for every Operating Systems. Meaning, if you are going to deploy this to multiple OS versions, I would investigate the actual problem you dealing which, also applies to the concerned Operating System.